# In which scenario Ignite diagnostics will be generated?

Tags: java, ignite, diagnostics

We are exploring Apache Ignite, and we want to understand the impact of keeping Ignite system property `IGNITE_DIAGNOSTIC_ENABLED` with default value true on production.

Answer (score 1):

With this setting an Ignite node conditionally checks internal structures in order to find long-running operations and print a log message. There's also a property `IGNITE_LONG_OPERATIONS_DUMP_TIMEOUT` controlling the threshold for duration of operations, by default it's 60_000 ms (operations longer than that are considered long-running).  I believe that this diagnostics machinery in almost harmless in terms of performance and stability and should be always enabled. It could serve two main purposes: troubleshooting and monitoring (alerting).